# Why this launcher button contains two applications?

Tags: launcher, libreoffice

Please take a look at this launcher button.

When I hover the mouse on it, it shows the name of LibreOffice Calc.

[image]

If I right click on it, it shows two applications,

[image]

`New Spreadsheet` and `Terminal`

If simply click on the launcher, a new terminal appears. This never starts LibreOffice Calc.

I can start LibreOffice only if I right click on it and then select and click 
`New Spreadsheet`.

Moreover, as you can see, it shows an option to `Lock to Launcher`. But nothing happens (change to unlock like others) when this option is selected.

I am utterly surprised since I do not remember changing anything special except regular updates.

Other launcher buttons are fine.

Could you please tell me how do I debug this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the calc.desktop with gedit (or your normal editor). On my computer it is situated in /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/xdg/calc.desktop. If not check /usr/share/applications.

Edit the name in [Desktop Entry] to Name=LibreOffice Calc (instead of Name=Terminal) and the Exec to Exec=libreoffice --calc %U (instead of probably Exec=terminal).
Best,

Comment: Things are fine after a logout and login. Very strange. I was trying to find the reason rather than how to correct it at this moment. I would still like to find the reason.